# How does Feytouched to Half-fey Level Adjustment work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

What is the overall LA of taking [*Feytouched*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sp/20040213a) and then taking the transition class to [*Half-Fey*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sp/20040319a)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LA +2, same as for half-fey.

The whole point of transition classes is that the starting template is considered to get you part of the way to the end template, so you can transition to the end template by making up the difference in LA and gaining the remaining abilities. So feytouched’s LA +1 has some of the features of the LA +2 half-fey, and the transition class allows you to take on the second LA and gain what feytouched is missing. Afterward, you are a half-fey creature and not really a feytouched creature any more, because those benefits are part of being a half-fey now.<sup>1</sup>

1. <sub>This isn’t to say you actually lose the feytouched benefits or anything—just that feytouched + the transition class = half-fey. Or at least that’s the theory—there is actually a **major** discrepancy here. Where feytouched are immune to all mind-affecting effects, half-fey are only immune to effects of the Enchantment school—all of which are mind-affecting, but don’t encompass all mind-affecting effects. That makes the feytouched immunity much better than the half-fey one, so a half-fey who started as a feytouched is that much better off than a regular half-fey. This *seems*
   like an oversight, but it’s hard to say for sure.</sub>

Comment: Would the LA buyoff be 6 or 9 levels?

Comment: @Cellheim You are talking about two variant systems from two different books. They absolutely never considered one another. But 9th is right out—you never have LA +3, so that wouldn’t come up. The real question is whether you could have feytouched and LA +1, buy that off at 3rd, and then transition to half-fey for another LA +1 and buy that off at 6th. Per my answer to your previous question, I would not allow that, and would make you take six levels to buy off the second LA (and *that* would happen at 9th).

Comment: @KRyan While I do the opposite. Once you have bought off the LA, you have an LA of 0 (zero). If you subsequently gain another LA, it doesn't magically stack with the previous (now non-existent) LA. But that's me and how I read and understood those paragraphs. Very good point on the immunity, though. It becomes one of those things where there is an obvious difference in final results.

Comment: @nijineko There is a separate question about that that you may want to answer, if you have an interest. But I’ll note that—while a reasonable enough choice for running the game—the text does not really support you very well, in my opinion.

Comment: @KRyan You may be right, I'll have to reread it then. I'm probably combining ideas from the savage progressions articles anyhow, as a fusion of those two rules made the most sense to me, plus some things I've read on the various designers private forums/blogs led me to see a level by level bias as the RAI based on their comments.

Comment: @KRyan Wait, are you saying that you would add the LA gained from a second unrelated template to the LA of the first template even if it had already been bought off before acquiring the second template? Or just when they're closely related in the way of a transition class?

Comment: @Cellheim You already have a question on that subject, that I have already answered at length. These comments are not the place to re-ask that question. But, as always, *there are no real answers here.* The variant in *UA* is incomplete; it doesn’t even mention templates to begin with. All we can give you is our opinions and/or our speculation about what they might have meant.

Comment: @KRyan Apologies, I believe I misunderstood your previous answer.